# Difference between two YUM python package

Tags: centos, package-management, python, yum

I have a question about the yum Python packages.

In the YUM repository there are two different packages.

1. python34.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000

[image: list of packages with their descriptions, one of which is 'python34.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000']

2. python34u.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000

[image: list of packages with their descriptions, one of which is 'python34u.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000']

The only difference that I see is the "u".

What does the "u" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [IUS repository](https://ius.io/GettingStarted/) added to your server. They have a [naming convention](https://ius.io/Philosophy/#naming-convention) for their packages:

```
In addition to appending the major and minor version numbers, most IUS packages also have a "u" suffix.
```

You can verify which repositories you have enabled with `yum repolist` command. You can also check information about specific package with `yum info package-name`.